# Using Textbox pasting event in Code Behind with MVVM Design Pattern?

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, code-behind

So I'm new to the popular MVVM design pattern used in WPF. I have a textbox for which I only want to accept a numeric input. Currently, my User Control has it's DataContext set to my ViewModel. My question is if the code below should also be in my ViewModel or is it fine to have it in my User Control (View) as per the MVVM design pattern?

```
private static readonly Regex num = new Regex("[^0-9.-]+");

private void ValidationEvent(object sender, TextCompositionEventArgs e)
{
    e.Handled = num.IsMatch(e.Text);
}

private void PastingEvent(object sender, DataObjectPastingEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.DataObject.GetDataPresent(typeof(String)))
    {
        if (num.IsMatch((String)e.DataObject.GetData(typeof(String))))
        {
            e.CancelCommand();
        }
    }
    else
    {
        e.CancelCommand();
    }
}
```

These events are binded to a textbox in my view like this:

```
<TextBox Text="{Binding Number}" DataObject.Pasting="PastingEvent" PreviewTextInput="ValidationEvent" Width="70" Margin="5 5 10 5" Style="{StaticResource PlaceHolderTextBox}" />
```

Should all of this be in the associated ViewModel as per best practice?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A cleaner approach, IMHO, is to either use `INotifyDataErrorInfo` or `ValidationRule`

They both have their place in validation scheme. `INotifyDataErrorInfo` is more closely bound to the type, and `ValidationRule` is loosely coupled to validate an instance.

Here is some information on how to use [Validation Rules](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wpf/data/how-to-implement-binding-validation?view=netframework-4.7.2) and [INotifyDataErrorInfo](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/22506.asynchronous-validation-in-wpf-using-the-mvvm-pattern-and-inotifydataerrorinfo.aspx)

Comment: I looked into this, specifically INotifyDataErrorInfo and it feels like a needlessly roundabout way of letting the user know his input is incorrect instead of simply preventing him from putting the incorrect input in the first place. Why would you recommend this over simply the two functions I mentioned above in place?

Comment: Good point. 1-Reusable code. 2-View isn't responsible for validation.